# .env.local file in Next.js not setting up properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js

when I create a **.env.local** file in my project root, it's not setting up properly.

[image]

in the file, I have my API key like so

```
API_KEY=SOME_API_KEY
```

Then when i try to access it in **getServerSideProps** with **process.env.API_KEY**, it doesn't work. When I **console.log(process.env.API_KEY)** i get **undefiend**. Which I assume is because the file isn't set up properly?

I even tried installing **dotenv** but I know you don't need that with Next.js.

**next config file**

```
module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
}
```

Comment: please stop the server and then run again, in case you need expose the var you should named it NEXT_PUBLIC_

Comment: do you have custom next config file ?

Comment: Uninstall `dotenv` and restart your server. You don't need `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix to use env vars inside `getServerSideProps`. You can also try things mentioned in this thread: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12754

Comment: @Shyam updated the post with the next config file. I was reading documentation and it didn't mention anything about changing or adding something in the config file

Comment: so .env.local works with +v9.4, which version you are using?

Comment: @Shyam currently on 11.1.2

Comment: dotenv not installed in build and my env.local not working with NEXT_PUBLIC on client components.

Answer (score 8):

You’ll notice that the browser will log `undefined`. This happens since the environment variable is only defined on our server so far.

Since Next.js 9.4, Next.js will make all environment variables that start with `NEXT_PUBLIC_` available to the client without any further configuration!

1. Create .env (all environments), .env.development (development environment), .env.production (production environment), .env.local (local enviroment)
2. Add the prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_` to all of your environment variables.

   ```
    NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/
   ```
3. Use with prefix `process.env`

   ```
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL
   ```
4. Stop the server and restart it:

   ```
   npm run dev

   OR 

   yarn dev
   ```

Comment: React Js uses REACT_APP & Nect js uses NEXT_PUBLIC

Thanks its working

Comment: Sadly in my situation I was already doing all these things per docs, and had restarted the server and this does not fix my issue.

Comment: It works, but how do you handle the env variables for production since using NEXT_PUBLIC on production warns about security? I am thinking on something like
console.log(NEXT_PUBLIC_ENV_VAR ?? ENV_VAR) 

but I am not sure if it's a good solution

Answer (score 2):

`.env.local` works with +v9.4.

if you are using older version please try with next config file https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/environment-variables.

Note:
Next.js will replace `process.env.customKey` with 'customKey' at build time. Trying to destructure process.env variables won't work due to the nature of webpack

Comment: Ty, this worked. I'm on version 11.1.2, so it's weird that .env.local doesn't work

Comment: .env.local doesn't work for me either. Using the latest Next. Really weird

Comment: @user.io can you share reproduction link or link to your repo?

Comment: Oops, it's okay now. It was actually my graphql-codegen that wasn't seeing it. By setting the dotenv path it now works:

DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=./.env.local

Comment: okay, @user.io 

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server solved it for me as in @Igmer Rodriguez comment above .