# When deploying app to local server the environmental variables are not being loaded

Tags: next.js, environment-variables, moralis

I am connecting this app to **Moralis**.
There are no errors in the console.
I am expecting to see this in the Terminal...

```
 Info- loaded env from …
```

I *hardcoded* my env variables because it's the only thing that would work.
Using "NEXT_PUBLIC_" gave me errors.

`env.local`

```
serverUrl = 'https://8oyk5t00zoyz.usemoralis.com:2053/server' 
appId = 'l9iAGdkJCtFrMAlp8ot12XVtgbeXiwul9iKhgZD9'
```

`_app.js`

```
function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  
  return (
    <MoralisProvider
    serverUrl= 'https://8oyk5t00zoyz.usemoralis.com:2053/server'
    appId= 'l9iAGdkJCtFrMAlp8ot12XVtgbeXiwul9iKhgZD9'
      
    >
    <Component {...pageProps} />

        </MoralisProvider >
        
  )
}
export default MyApp
```

`index.js`

```
const styles = {
  container: `h-full w-full flex bg-[#fff]`
}

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Sidebar /> 
      {/*<Main/> */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: _"Using "NEXT_PUBLIC" gave me errors"_ - What errors? If you want to access environment variables inside your `_app.js` component you have to expose them using `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530624/env-local-file-in-next-js-not-setting-up-properly/73287421#73287421)